# Left and Right aligned Texts in 1 TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

There is compound drawable option in `TextView` to avoid using a parent `ViewGroup` and an `ImageView` next to `TextView`. Which is neat and faster in performance as said by lint. I'm trying to do something similar. A `TextView` with 2 texts inside, one aligned to left, one aligned to write. Sounds strange but it will only allowed for single line `TextView`.

And to do that, I can extend `TextView` and set its gravity to right side. And inside `onDraw` let the super class draw on right side, and then draw text on left side.

Problem is, I'm not really sure about all this. My question is, will there be a big performance difference ? I dont have any slower device to test. I will be using this `TextView` inside an item layout of GridView, Item layout already have many views, it would be nice if I could merge some views to one. But again, will there be a performance difference, like noticeable by user ? And if there will be, the approach I will be using by extending the `TextView`, is there any problem or I should try some other way ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the issue with using two TextView in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read I would imagine that you are using a custom adapter for your GridView?

If so, cant you just use TableRow and insert 2 TextViews inside that with each layout weight set to 1. Then you will have 2 columns in one row?

Just an idea.

Comment: Yes, same can be done with `LinearLayout` too but I don't want to use 2 `TextView`s. The question was about performance, please read the last para of question. Thank you :)

Comment: I think your best bet is to just extend TextView and attempt it. Try finding a slower device or emulate it. I would be interested in seeing your code that extends TextView and the xml too. Goodluck